# How to completely fill the activity layout in navigation drawer fragment from all sides?

Tags: android, xml

I have linked my image here.

I wanna to fill an activity completely inside the fragment of navigation drawer

I am uploading my three layout files which i used in my project. Please tell me where is the problem

recycleritems.xml This my layout file for cardview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
cardview:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
cardview:cardBackgroundColor="#C5EEEE"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"

        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:padding="5dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Android"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />


        </RelativeLayout> </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Main.xml  This is my file for main activity

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragmentCon"
tools:context=".util.VegDetails.VegMain"
></FrameLayout>
```

Fragment.xml This file contains the recycler view

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"/></FrameLayout>
```

These are my three layouts files

Comment: If that's what you want to do, why did you make it an activity in the first place ? Convert it into a fragment and use that fragment

Comment: Just remove padding from activity layout

Comment: wait, Activity in fragment? or fragment in activity?

Comment: `I have linked my image here.` where ???

Comment: Activity in a fragment. Like when i choose an option from navigation drawer sliding menu I got an activity which show me food products. But my concern is that that view is not completely fill inside the fragment.

Comment: You please see this image https://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1ASUC_enIN759IN759&biw=1366&bih=588&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=ecommerce+app&oq=ecommerce+app&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l4.2283.2787.0.3068.4.4.0.0.0.0.260.260.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.1.258....0.3gSzv9B9Zyo#imgrc=fZUdwluDWgBg1M:

Comment: Like this image activity fills the completely inside fragment but in my project there is a margin or gap from all four sides.

Comment: post layout xml codes